# Vertical concatenation in a df based on column value_python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, concatenation

Is there any way to concatenate vertically a specific column from my df (concat1), considering/filtering values from another column (col_value)?

My df looks like this:

```
col_value         concat1      

data1             x;y;z    
data1             d;f;h
data1             p;c;j
data2             s;k;a 
data3             a;w;q
data2             o;i;s 
data3             e;q;j
data4             d;f;n
data4             q;f;k
```

Expected output:

```
col_value         vertical_concat

data1             x;y;z;d;f;h;p;c;j    
data1             x;y;z;d;f;h;p;c;j
data1             x;y;z;d;f;h;p;c;j
data2             s;k;a;o;i;s
data3             a;w;q;e;q;j
data2             s;k;a;o;i;s
data3             a;w;q;e;q;j
data4             d;f;n;q;f;k
data4             d;f;n;q;f;k
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e["vertical_concat"] = e.groupby("col_value").transform(lambda x: ";".join(x.unique()))
```

as per the response of Julio here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/vertical-concatenation-in-a-df-based-on-column-value-python